# Сделать блок поверх другого

Tags: css

При наведении на товар появляется краткое описание которое должно перекрывать собой все остальные блоки, но на практике это не так. Задал блоку position: absolute; и z-index: 999; к сожалению не работает как должно и заголовок следующего блока перекрывает описание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код? Возможно у заголовка есть свой z-index

Comment: сайт http://burzhuyka.1gb.ua/

Comment: @ValeryPerets Миссия данного сайта — база знаний. Для того, чтобы данный вопрос был полезен широким массам, то надо привести минимальный вопроизведимый код прямо в вопросе. Также давать ссылку на сторонний ресурс бессмысленно, так как когда вы уже решите эту проблему, то от ссылки толку не будет.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.name__product').hover(function(e) {
    $('.blockInform').toggle();

  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block__product {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container__block {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.blockInform {
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 30px 0 0 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #D8BFD8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container__block">
    <div class="jumbotron block__product">
      <h2 class="name__product">Булерьян</h2>
      <p>от 7777 грн</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Заказать</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron block__product">
      <h2 class="name__product2">Булерьян</h2>
      <p>от 7777 грн</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Заказать</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron blockInform">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
    <h4>Эта печь работает на дровах – топливе, которое всегда доступно. Кроме того, ее расход минимизирован за счет уникальной конструкции печи.</h4>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```